# Why systematic divergence between ^VIX and VXX?

Tags: vix

Why is there systematic negative divergence between the VIX index and the VXX ETF meant to track it?

http://finance.yahoo.com/q/bc?s=%5EVIX&t=5y&l=on&z=l&q=l&c=vxx

Comment: Come on now, Rich, dont be lazy.
http://www.ipathetn.com/static/pdf/vix-prospectus.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because VXX is not designed to track the spot VIX. http://blogs.cfainstitute.org/insideinvesting/2014/02/12/doing-what-it-says-on-the-tin-the-value-of-volatility-etps/